# facebook web app : Safari always shows facebook prompts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, safari

So I have a facebook app, it works. However, when I use my web app on Safari, it always prompts the user with

> you previously logged in to [app name] with Facebook. Would you like
>   to continue ?

For every actions.(It's about planning posts, editing them or deleting them)
When on Chrome for instance, it goes through Facebook and redirects to the web app seemlessly.

It was not doing that before, so I don't understand why it does now.

So I would like to know what is up with Safari and if there is a way to make it run like in Chrome, which is how I intend it to be.

Thank you

Comment: Could by a problem with acceptance of 3rd-party cookies, Safari by default treats those a little stricter than other browsers.

Comment: mmmh still odd. It used not to do that. Just figured it does today, but I recall seeing it working like Chrome previously.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this?

Comment: unfortunately not. I wish, it doesn't look pretty, I like when things are seemless, but with the latest Apple conference, I doubt there's a way and I believe they'll do more things like this.